# Group and get the latest month data from the map

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap

I have a map as follows:

```
rupFeedDC.forEach(rl -> rl.getTransactionDate()
                          .toLocalDateTime()
                          .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS));

Map<Timestamp, List<STUP>> timestampListMap =
    rupFeedDC.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(STUP::getTransactionDate));
```

Now, I want to get date which contains the latest month.

For example:
for the map:

```
map.put("23/04/2017", someList);
map.put("21/04/2017", someList);
map.put("03/03/2017", someList);
map.put("04/02/2017", someList);
map.put("09/01/2017", someList);
```

I want to have only the key "23/04/2017", because it consists of the latest month. Can anyone please suggest me what can I do for it?

Comment: I have changed it, thats my mistake

Comment: yes that is  java.sql.Timestamp class

Comment: Your initial `forEach` operation has no effect. It truncates your timestamps to dates alright, but doesn’t store the result back into your `STUP` objects.

Comment: Is there any logical difference between “the latest month” you want to get and just getting the latest date? Apparently not, as `23/04/2017` and `21/04/2017` have the same month and you’re saying you only want to get `23/04/2017`, the one with the latest *day*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your key is a `java.sql.Timestamp`, you can take advantage of the fact that it implements `Comparable`. Modify your stream pipeline to generate a `TreeMap` (in which the keys are sorted in ascending order), and the last key will be the latest timestamp:

```
TreeMap<Timestamp, List<STUP>> timestampListMap =
    rupFeedDC.stream()
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(STUP::getTransactionDate,
                                            TreeMap::new,
                                            Collectors.toList()));
Timestamp last = timestampListMap.lastKey();
```

Answer (score 2):

There is not much sense in performing a grouping operation when you are interested in just one group. Since these groups are determined by a property, you are just looking for all elements having the same value for that property.

So first, determine the value of that property, i.e. the maximum timestamp:

```
Timestamp latest = rupFeedDC.stream()
    .map(STUP::getTransactionDate)
    .max(Comparator.naturalOrder())
    .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("no entries"));
```

Then, collect all elements having that property value

```
List<STUP> items = rupFeedDC.stream()
    .filter(item -> item.getTransactionDate().equals(latest))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you still think you need a `Map` containing that one group, you can use

```
Map<Timestamp, List<STUP>> timestampListMap = Collections.singletonMap(latest, items);
```

Your question’s code suggests that you want to process the dates at day granularity (though it’s not working), which you can achieve with

```
LocalDateTime latest = rupFeedDC.stream()
    .map(item -> item.getTransactionDate().toLocalDateTime().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS))
    .max(Comparator.naturalOrder())
    .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("no entries"));
List<STUP> items = rupFeedDC.stream()
    .filter(item -> item.getTransactionDate().toLocalDateTime()
                        .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS).equals(latest))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
Map<LocalDateTime, List<STUP>> timestampListMap = Collections.singletonMap(latest, items);
```

As a side note, it makes no sense to say that you want “the latest month” when both, your code and your explanation by example indicate that you actually want the latest ***day***.

Comment: Holger, in the lasst snippet you are converting each timestamp to `LocalDateTime` and truncating twice. Isn’t that a greater waste than grouping all even though you only need the last group?

Comment: @OleV.V. Both approaches are linear regarding the required CPU time, but grouping has a significantly higher memory footprint, as it allocates and populates lists containing the members of each group, plus the map holding them, whereas the last snippet of my answer still allocates only the one list containing the very elements the OP is interested in.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Optional<Entry<LocalDate, List<STUP>>> latest = rupFeedDC.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(rl -> rl.getTransactionDate()
                    .toLocalDateTime()
                    .toLocalDate()))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .max(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry<LocalDate, List<STUP>>::getKey));
```

This will give you just the map entry for the latest date (or an empty `Optional` in case the list was empty). Use for example like this:

```
    latest.ifPresent(e -> {
        LocalDate latestDate = e.getKey();
        List<STUP> latestList = e.getValue();
        // ...
    });
```

If it turns out that grouping all objects (the ones from earlier dates too) has too big of a memory footprint, here’s a suggestion for how to avoid that:

```
    Optional<LocalDate> latestDate = rupFeedDC.stream()
            .map(STUP::getTransactionDate)
            .max(Comparator.naturalOrder())
            .map(ts -> ts.toLocalDateTime().toLocalDate());
    latestDate.ifPresent(d -> {
        List<STUP> latestList = rupFeedDC.stream()
                .filter(rl -> rl.getTransactionDate().toLocalDateTime()
                                    .toLocalDate()
                                    .equals(d))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        // ...
    });
```

Better still if you could use `LocalDateTime` in your `STUP` class instead of `Timestamp`. The `Timestamp` is long outdated, and this change would save a conversion for each object in your original list.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the keys of the map and find the latest.

```
Set<String> keys = map.keySet();
        Date latest = null;

        for (String s : keys) {
            if(latest==null){
                latest=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(s);
            }else{
                //check if current is latest that 'latest'
                Date current = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(s);
                if(current.after(latest)){
                    latest = current;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group and search for max element in a single `collect` operation. Something along the lines:

```
    Comparator<STUP> comparingTransactionDate =
            Comparator.comparing(STUP::getTransactionDate);

    List<STUP> result = rupFeedDC.stream().collect(() -> new ArrayList<STUP>(), (list,  newItem) -> {
        if (!list.isEmpty()) {
            STUP existingItem = list.get(0);
            int comparingExistingItemToNewItem = 
                    comparingTransactionDate.compare(existingItem, newItem);
            if (comparingExistingItemToNewItem < 0) {
                list.clear();
                list.add(newItem);
            } else if (comparingExistingItemToNewItem == 0){
                list.add(newItem);
            }
        }
        else {
            list.add(newItem);
        }
    }, (list1, list2) -> {
        if (list1.isEmpty()) {
            list1.addAll(list2);
        }
        else if (!list2.isEmpty()) {
            STUP left = list1.get(0);
            STUP right = list2.get(0);
            int leftComparedToRight = comparingTransactionDate.compare(left, right);
            if (leftComparedToRight == 0) {
                list1.addAll(list2);
            } else if (leftComparedToRight < 0) {
                list1.clear();
                list1.addAll(list2);
            }
        }
    });
```

This approach saves you the construction of the complete `Map<Timestamp, List<STUP>>` which isn't really needed to find the latest element. It might be helpful if you have many `STUP` elements and want to save the memory.